# django manytomanyfield fetch unique countryname

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)    
class DeliveryMethod(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
```

I want to fetch all country name from DeliveryMethod model(country name should not be repeated into output list.)
I tried query

```
>>> DeliveryMethod.objects.all().values_list('country__name')
[(u'Pakistan',), (u'Pakistan',), (u'India',), (u'Pakistan',), (u'Kenya',), (u'I
ndia',), (u'Pakistan',), (u'Kenya',)]
```

I want output like below given list.

```
[(u'Pakistan',), (u'India',), (u'Kenya',)]
```

Comment: you can use distinct() after all and put values_list after that and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer. use distinct after all() method.

```
>>DeliveryMethod.objects.all().distinct().values_list('country__name')
```